# JQuery selector returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This html code was generated of my php code, but I copied this out of the HTML code of the browser.

The console.log prints out undefined. I don't know why. It's probably a really dumb mistake, like always. Thank you for your help.

```js
$('.show').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var div = $("div#" + id);
  console.log(div.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Heading <a href='#' class='show' id='2962'>+</a></h3>
<div class='.slidetoggle' id='2962' style='display: none;'>
  <p>Test!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the `.show` element is an `a`, not a `div`. The selector is wrong:

```
var div = $("a#" + id);
```

*Update:*

> You are right, but I want to show the div, not the a

In this case you need to use DOM traversal to find the relevant element. Your current code doesn't work as you have duplicate `id` attributes. This is invalid as they must be unique. Try this:

```js
$('.show').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('h3').next('.slidetoggle').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.slidetoggle { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Heading <a href="#" class="show">+</a></h3>
<div class="slidetoggle">
  <p>Test!</p>
</div>

<h3>Another Heading <a href="#" class="show">+</a></h3>
<div class="slidetoggle">
  <p>Another Test!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right, but I want to show the div, not the a

Comment: What do you mean 'show the div'? Do you mean you want to geth the HTML of the following div element?

Comment: Exactly. The div has the style 'display: none;' because I want to show/hide it with the click() method.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan There is duplicate IDs. There is an `a` and a `div` that shares the same ID. So technically `("div#" + id)` is correct. The problem is that the ID starts with a digit.

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan! Saved my evening!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to comment yet so I will have to give it as an answer, but the element you want is an nchor but your jQuery selector is targeting a  element.